# Does move_uploaded_file() automatically deletes the temporary uploaded file after SUCCESSful Move?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

My Question is:  "Does `move_uploaded_file()` automatically deletes the temporary uploaded file after successful move ?"

Just to get out of the confusion that do i need to do this:

```
// Successful upload
if ( move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $destination) ) {
  unlink($file['tmp_name']);
  return TRUE;
} else {
  // Upload Failed
  unlink($file['tmp_name']);
  return FALSE;
}
```

Or is it not needed at all?

Comment: Yes you do not need to remove it manually. In fact not `move_uploaded_file` removes it.

Comment: @jeroen yeah, we can use `file_exists` too. I was just using `print_r($file);` to see the temp_filename

Comment: IS it So that IF the `tmp_file` is deleted by The PHP's Garbage Collector if `move_uploaded_file` Fails or any case when script execution completes ?.

Comment: Any case it will be deleted

Comment: THis thread should become Complete in its sense of clarity in all cases ... :)

Comment: Thank You All for your courteous Participation.

Comment: Thank you @Konrad for the EDIT, changing `does not needed at all` to `is it not needed at all` in the main question.  
Just came to know about your inclination towards History, Philosophy and Languages like Japanese.  cheers **; )**

Comment: if language experts are here like you within the coders, i think we don't have to worry about even the smaller mistakes we make in the hurry.

Comment: Happy Q & A on [_**StackOverFlown**_](http://StackOverFlow.com).
The link is valid but Actually **The Stack** IS **_Over Flown_. ;P** **StackOverFlow** _is_ A Too Well Thought NAME. I appreciate.

Comment: Just to Update the newbies here. I have Checked and Traced `file_exists($file['tmp_name'])` before & after `move_uploaded_file(.....)`. It gives me **1** /TRUE Before `Move_Uploaded....` and FALSE afterwards, CONFIRMING THAT the PHP Garbage Collector **DELETES** the TEMPORARY FILES after Script Execution completes FROM its TEMP_DIR _DEFINED_ in **PHP.ini**. (I am Using XAMPP)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to manually `unlink()` the temporary file; PHP cleans up after itself after a successful upload. The function is called ***move*_uploaded_file**, not ***copy*_uploaded_file**.

Comment: i agree with you. it MOVES not COPIES.

Comment: _Just to **Update the newbies** here_ **:** I have **Checked and Traced** `file_exists($file['tmp_name'])` before & after `move_uploaded_file(.....)`. It gives me **1** /TRUE **Before** `Move_Uploaded....` and FALSE **afterwards**, CONFIRMING THAT the PHP Garbage Collector **DELETES** the TEMPORARY FILES after Script Execution completes FROM its TEMP_DIR _DEFINED_ in **PHP.ini**. (I am Using XAMPP).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

> Function description:     This function checks to ensure that the file
>   designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was
>   uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid,
>   it will be moved to the filename given by destination.
>
> This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that
>   anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the
>   user, or even to other users on the same system.

So we see here:

If the file is valid, it will be **moved** to the filename given by destination.

Comment: move_uploaded_file doesnot delete it after move.

Comment: It assumes removing it, but `not directly`. Uploaded file is in temporary storage.

Comment: i agree with you. it MOVES not COPIES.

Comment: Thumbs Up @BogdanBurim ! Just Selected the answer yesterday which I thought Short and Appropriate, no doubt based on other ANSWERS. In SHort Everyone Else was **RIGHT TOO**. As I already read the PHP.NET Manual, but was still confused about it. Because like the PHP.NET Manual has a known atmosphere about Uploads on the MAX_FILE_SIZE _HTML FORM FIELD Issue_.

Comment: **@BogdanBurim you made a _Nice Contribution matey!_ **

Answer (score 2):

Temporary File is Deleted Automatically. You dont have to delete it manually. `move_uploaded_file` function also not delete this temporary file.

Comment: You are right bro. thanks. but i will have to choose a more clear & explanatory Answer.  

Currently making my choice.